# Can't get light to turn on with gl.glEnable

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm writing a java program with opengl and I'm trying to get it where the user would select something like lighting on in a JMenu and then it would turn the lighting on in the house/barn... I have a method called LightOn that I put gl.glEnable(gl.GL_LIGHT0); but it just doesn't seem to turn on when I call it from the action performed... Is there something I'm missing from my code that I'm supposed to use instead since I have tried it with a boolean.. So the boolean starts off as false and when the JMenuItem is clicked the actionPerformed will turn the boolean to true and call the method LightOn. In the display method I have what the light is supposed to be

Snippet of code in display method for lighting:

```
float [] whiteLight = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
float [] ambientLight = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f}; //default
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, whiteLight,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, whiteLight,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight,0);

float [] lightPosition = {25, 25, 25, 1};
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_POSITION, lightPosition,0);

float [] diffuse_mp = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};//red
    //gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, ambientLight,0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse_mp,0);


boolean light = false;
public static void LightOn(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    boolean light = true;
    //gl.glEnable(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHT0);  

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Lighting On"))
    {
        light = true;
        LightOn(canvas);
        System.out.println("Light on");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried with also enabling `GL_LIGHTING`? The line doing this is in your code, but currently commented out. Also, while I don't know how this works in JOGL, you'll have to make sure that all your OpenGL calls are made in a thread that has a current OpenGL context. On many systems/platforms, it's common to create a separate rendering thread. If that's the case, making OpenGL calls from the UI thread will not work.

Comment: Isn't there a problem of variable shadowing? A local variable and a package protected fields are both called "light". Please show us a complete example.

Comment: You should avoid legacy OpenGL